# Celerity and https

Tags: jruby

When I try to connect to an https site with celerity I only get SSLPeerUnverifiedExceptions lite this

```
require "rubygems"
require "celerity"

browser = Celerity::Browser.new({:secure_ssl =>false,:proxy =>"localhost:3128"})
browser.goto('https://www.google.com')
```

generates this:

NativeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
                          goto at /home//Local/jruby-1.6.0.RC3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/celerity-0.8.8/lib/celerity/browser.rb:100
  rescue_status_code_exception at /home//Local/jruby-1.6.0.RC3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/celerity-0.8.8/lib/celerity/container.rb:796
                          goto at /home//Local/jruby-1.6.0.RC3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/celerity-0.8.8/lib/celerity/browser.rb:99
                        (root) at celtest.rb:5

any suggestions on how to get this to work?